# UIButton simultaneous clicks action depending count

Tags: uibutton, ibaction, swift4.2

If user clicks 1 and less than 5 times *click/press* then `OneTimeClickAction` **func** should called,

If User simultaneously or consecutively 5 times and less than 10 times *click/press* then `FiveTimeClickAction` **func** should get called

and If User simultaneously or consecutively more than 10 times *click/press* then `tenTimeClickAction` **func** should get called.

```
{
        guard let tempDate = self.lastTappedAt else { return }
        let elapsed = Date().timeIntervalSince(tempDate)
        let duration = Int(elapsed)
        print(duration)
        if duration < 2 {
            tapCount = tapCount + 1
            // return
        } else {
            tapCount = 0
        }
        self.lastTappedAt = Date()

        if tapCount > 9 {
            let dispatchTime = DispatchTime.now() + 3.0
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: dispatchTime) {
                self.didTappedTenTimes(.happy)
            }

            return
        }
        if ((tapCount < 6) && (duration > 2)) {
            let dispatchTime = DispatchTime.now() + 3.0
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: dispatchTime) {
                self.didTappedFiveTimes(.react)
            }
            return
        }
        if tapCount == 0{
            let dispatchTime = DispatchTime.now() + 3.0
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: dispatchTime) {
                self.didTapped(.wink)
            }
        }
    }
```

please feel free to let me know more about the same in depth and suggest me to deal this in better way.

Thanks

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: If I clicked more than up to 5 times then its winking , reacting. If I click 10 times then its winking, reacting and happy as well.

I want one action - like,
If User clicks 1 time then wink
 if user clicks 5 then react.
If user clicks 10 times then happy

Comment: not under stent. what is the problem in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I understand you don't want to track actual time when button is pressed, but only count taps in some reasonable time, assuming multiple taps one after another belonging to same action (wink, happy, react).

```
var tapCount = 0
var lastTappedAt: Date = Date()

func scheduleCheckResult() {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 1) {
        let timePassedSinceLastTap = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince(self.lastTappedAt))
        print("last tap was \(timePassedSinceLastTap) ago")

        // Wait a bit more for resolving final reaction. Adjust if you want quicker/slower taps (more than 1s for slower, less for quiceker)
        guard timePassedSinceLastTap > 1 else {
            return self.scheduleCheckResult()
        }

        print("FINISHED WITH: \(self.tapCount)")
        // Verify result
        switch self.tapCount {
        case let n where n >= 10:
            print("Super duper happy")
        case let n where n >= 5:
            print("Very happy")
        default:
            print("Medium happy")
        }

        // Reset state
        self.tapCount = 0
    }
}

@IBAction func didTap() {
    if tapCount == 0 {
        scheduleCheckResult()
    }
    lastTappedAt = Date()
    tapCount += 1
}
```